# Adding a Field 'Name on Credit Card' to Product Payment Page

Tags: commerce

I'd like to add a field called 'Name on Credit Card' to the product payment form on my site but I can't figure out how to add fields to that form. I'm using Commerce and the PayPal WPP module. The default fields for the payment page include only cc number, cc type (visa, etc.), csv, and expiration date.

Anyone know how to add a field to that payment form?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to **implement some Commerce Payment form builder callback function within a custom module**, in order to **alter the existing form** that PayPal WPP provides.

The payment form is generated using **this callback**:

[CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_submit_form](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites%21all%21modules%21commerce%21modules%21payment%21commerce_payment.api.php/function/CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_submit_form/DC)

You will need to **create a custom form building callback function**, and then **use a hook to change the module's form building callback function name**.

Unfortunately I'm not sure off hand which hook you need to use, but the following links could guide you in the right direction:

- [HOOK_form_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!checkout!includes!commerce_checkout.pages.inc/function/commerce_checkout_form/7)
- [commerce_payment.api.php](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites%21all%21modules%21commerce%21modules%21payment%21commerce_payment.api.php/DC)

Whatever you do, **don't edit the PayPal WPP module directly**, but you probably already know that.

**EDIT**

See **line 182 of commerce_paypal_wpp.module** for the form building callback you need to replicate and change in a custom module.

**EDIT**

I just found the correct hook for you to implement, in order to point the payment method to use your custom CALLBACK function. It comes from **commerce_payment.api.php**. See extract from module function comments below (line 129):

```
callbacks (optional): an array of callback function names for the various
types of callback required for all the payment method operations, arguments
per callback in parentheses:
```

[hook_commerce_payment_method_info_alter](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites%21all%21modules%21commerce%21modules%21payment%21commerce_payment.api.php/function/hook_commerce_payment_method_info_alter/DC)

Comment: Thank you. This is new to me. I'm already using hook_form_alter to modify the overall form (the payment method form snippet you speak of is also appearing on this main checkout form). So is it just a matter of adding the new field to the form with hook_form_alter() and then also calling and renaming the callback function somewhere in this same custom module file? What would I call the CALLBACK function? 'CALLBACK_function-name' or do I make up some other name to replace CALLBACK with? how do I link them to make sure hook_form_alter calls the new CALLBACK function? Sorry, new to this aspect.

Comment: You're almost there in your approach :) You don't need to add the new field via hook_form_alter, but rather within your custom CALLBACK function.

I was suggesting to try use hook_form_alter to change the callback function name used by paypal_wpp, but it might not be the right place to change it.

Comment: Actually just found the right hook for you to use to change the callback function. See edit #2 above.

Comment: Ok, I've made an attempt. Can you please give me some guidance on how to improve this? I made a new thread here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192333/how-to-correctly-edit-a-form-callback-to-add-fields-to-a-product-form

Comment: will try my best to get to it ASAP, busy day at the office :)